# Angular 4 dynamic form patchvalue an array

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a dynamic form based on the angular docs, I have a function that lets the user load their saved form. Currently i can patch the values of other form fields like textfield and radiobutton but I cant do it on an array since it's value is an array.
    I have the following code

```
if(value instanceof Array){
         value.forEach((subVal, index)=>{
           let a = subVal.value
           this.form.controls[key].patchValue({index,a})
         })
          //  
      }else{
      this.form.controls[key].patchValue(value);
      }
```

Comment: Can you share your array format?

Comment: can you replicate this in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I would recommencd making a function and create the form there. When you saved the record or create it, should call the function.

If you want to update just one value can use `.patchValue()`

Like this:

```
createForm(data: any){
  let newFormArray: FormGroup[] = [];
  for(let i = 0; i > data.length; i++){
    newFormArray.push(this.fb.group({
                    id: data[i].id,
                    name: data[i].name
     }));
  }
  this.form = this.fb.group({
       array: this.fb.array(newFormArray)
  })
}
```